# ER diagroms Composite Key representation in m;n relationship

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

Student:

```
student_id (Primary Key)
first_name
last_name
date_of_birth
contact_number
email_address
```

Course:

```
course_id (Primary Key)
course_name
course_code
department
```

Faculty:

```
faculty_id (Primary Key)
first_name
last_name
department
contact_number
email_address
```

Enrollment:

```
enrollment_id (Primary Key)
student_id (Foreign Key referencing Student)
course_id (Foreign Key referencing Course)
grade
```

How can you represent these in a ERd Is it ok to represent erollment as a relationship  as Student Enrols in courses?

Representing M:N relationships in ER

Comment: I'd say there is no definite answer there: Enrolment is a relationship with at least one proper attribute (`grade`), so I'd rather go with a full fledged entity, but whether this is worth it or not also depends on whether the model is conceptual-level vs implementation-level and how detailed you need to be. -- If nothing else comes up, I will make this comment into an answer: the answer essentially being "go for the most *readable*"...

Answer (score 0):

In your model, `Enrolment` could be represented in an [ERD](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/) either as:

- An entity, since the `enrollment_id` primary key gives it an own identity.  This entity would have two one-to many associations with `Student` and `Course` respectively; or as
- An associative entity, since enrolment implements clearly a many to many  association between `Student` and `Course` and it could not exist without any of the two.  Associative entities should not have their own identity however. You could therefore remove `enrolment_id` and use a combined primary key made of `student_id` and `course_id`. You'd just have to underline both of them in the attributes (assuming Chen notation).  If several enrolments are possible for the same student and course, you'd need a their component in the composite primary key (a simple sequential number, or a semester id).